# Angular - ngxDataTable - (page) event does not fire

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have a ngxDataTable, it works like a charm but...(page) event does not work as expected, it fires one time only, to the second page, but I have much more pages. How do I have it working?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce in a stackblitz ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid it's ipossible due to NDA signed.

Comment: I got the issue, just missed this attr - [limit]="(pages$|async).limit". Now it works. ))